# Stacking/Grouping command defined tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I am working on a package that extensively uses commands that take `pgfkeys` to produce a tikz picture. Below is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}
\newcommand{\example}[2][]{
\tikzset{
 /Example/.cd,
 caption/.store in=\Example@caption,
 caption=X,
 #1,
}
\draw [local bounding box=M] rectangle (1,1);
\node at (0.5,0.5) {\Example@caption};
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\example[caption=A];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives the following output, as expected:

[image: macro output]

(Bear in mind this is an example done for simplification, and does not reflect the complexity of the real commands, which contain many many more keys that do more complex things).

What I want to create is two new list environments that I can add one of the commands to multiple times with different key values. The resulting pictures are then "grouped" with a tikz drawn brace or "stacked" with a line extending down from the south west corner of a defined local bounding box within the command a certain length so it connects with the next picture if present (all will be of equal spacing, and each picture will have the same overall size):

[image: the stack and group]

What I'm ideally looking for is a list environment structure similar to this:

```
\begin{examplestack}
    \item \example[caption=A] 
    \item \example[caption=B] 
    \item \example[caption=C] 
\end{examplestack}

\begin{examplegroup}
    \item \example[caption=A] 
    \item \example[caption=B] 
    \item \example[caption=C] 
\end{examplegroup}
```

Both the stack and the group should have their origin offset within the `tikzpicture` canvas, the group at the tip of the brace, the stack at the bottom of the last line (the bottom of the "flagpole"). This is so they can be placed correctly if being overlayed on another layer (like a map).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proof of concept. Seems to work for this simple case at least. Lengths will need to be adjusted here and there, for example the vertical shift of each item is simply hardcoded to 1.2cm. In general, this is not a very flexible approach, I'm sure there are others who could do better.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}
\newcommand{\example}[2][]{
\tikzset{
 /Example/.cd,
 caption/.store in=\Example@caption,
 caption=X,
 #1,
}
\draw [local bounding box=M] rectangle (1,1);
\node at (0.5,0.5) {\Example@caption};
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{exitem}

\newenvironment{examplestack}{
\setcounter{exitem}{0}
\renewcommand\item{
% if you only want to draw a line between items
%\ifnum \value{exitem}>0
%  \draw ([xshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]current bounding box.south west) -- ++(0,-0.2cm);
%\fi
%
% if you also want the line below the last item -- not very elegant
\draw (0,{-(1.2cm+\theexitem*1.2cm)}) -- ++(0,-2mm);
%
\stepcounter{exitem}\scoped[yshift=-\theexitem*1.2cm]}
\tikzpicture
}{
%\draw (current bounding box.north west) -- ([yshift=-3pt]current bounding box.south west);
\node [above right] at (current bounding box.north west) {``Stack''};
\endtikzpicture
}

\newenvironment{examplegroup}{
\setcounter{exitem}{0}
\renewcommand\item{\stepcounter{exitem}\scoped[yshift=-\theexitem*1.2cm]}
\tikzpicture
}{
\draw ([shift={(5pt,3pt)}]current bounding box.north west) -| ([shift={(-3pt,-3pt)}]current bounding box.south west) -- ++(8pt,0)
 (current bounding box.west) -- ++(-5pt,0);

\node [above right] at (current bounding box.north west) {``Group''};
\endtikzpicture
}


\begin{document}
\begin{examplegroup}
\item\example[caption=A];
\item\example[caption=B];
\item\example[caption=C];
\end{examplegroup}

\begin{examplestack}
\item\example[caption=A];
\item\example[caption=B];
\item\example[caption=C];
\end{examplestack}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did take a shortcut in the "stack", by drawing a single long line instead of several shorter ones, let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the POC. I think I would rather have separate lines if possible, for better rendering. I'm seeing what I can come up with myself, but any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: @Crazymoomin I did think of a way of doing that, will edit later.

Comment: @Crazymoomin Updated. As I say though, it's hardly elegant and flexible ...

Answer (score 1):

I feel I should add an answer to this, as I've managed to come up with a better and more flexible solution than Torbjørn T's answer to the problem. Their solution didn't allow for pictures of varying height to have the same spacing between them. Through use of a length macro I was able to store the length of the previous picture and use it to offset the next, and using a coordinate set I was able to join them together in the "Stack".

**Important Note**: `\item` has been redefined to take one argument, so within the environments, you should use `\item{<picture>}` instead of `\item <picture>`.

This solution uses `xparse` for cleaner command and environment syntax, but a plain LaTeX solution could be used just as easily.

Preamble (plus the rest from the MWE):

```
\newcounter{exitem}
\newlength{\itemlength}
```

The "Stack" syntax:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{examplestack}{}{
\setlength{\itemlength}{0}
\begin{scope}
\setcounter{exitem}{0}
\RenewDocumentCommand\item{m}{
\scoped[yshift=-\itemlength, local bounding box=T]
##1;
\ifnum \value{exitem}>0
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\result{\value{exitem}-1}
\draw ($(M.south west) + (0, -0.25)$) -- (F\result);
\fi
\coordinate (F\arabic{exitem}) at (M.north west);
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{T}{north west}}{\pgfpointanchor{T}{south west}}
\addtolength{\itemlength}{\pgf@y-5pt} % 5pt is the spacing between pictures.
\stepcounter{exitem}}
}{\end{scope}}
```

The "Group" syntax:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{examplegroup}{}{
\setlength{\itemlength}{0}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=G]
\RenewDocumentCommand\item{m}{
\scoped[yshift=-\itemlength, local bounding box=T]
##1;
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{T}{north west}}{\pgfpointanchor{T}{south west}}
\addtolength{\itemlength}{\pgf@y-5pt}} % 5pt is the spacing between pictures.
}{
\draw ([shift={(5pt,3pt)}]G.north west) -| ([shift={(-3pt,-3pt)}]G.south west) -- ++(8pt,0)
 (G.west) -- ++(-5pt,0);
\end{scope}}
```

Examples:

```
\begin{examplegroup}
\item{\example[caption=A]}
\item{\example[caption=B]}
\item{\example[caption=C]}
\end{examplegroup}

\begin{examplestack}
\item{\example[caption=A]}
\item{\example[caption=B]}
\item{\example[caption=C]}
\end{examplestack}
```